# Error when creating a custom response message

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to implement an email verification system and the way I have got it working seems "hacky" but it seems to work well.

I've created a custom response in the return portion of the function, but I keep getting the following error:

```
The response content must be rendered before it can be iterated over.
```

The process is the standard: someone registers and when I go to save the User model I have a `send_mail()` function that sends out the email with a verification key. The user clicks the link and it passes the key like this:

```
/api/account/verify/849c40665175e56709855cc7aec2b16c05a4d977b3b083790334c6bc01f6e522
```

In the view you can see where I pull the key out and process everything. I'm guessing the error is because I'm using `Response()` in `get_queryset()`, but I'm not sure. If not, how do I create a custom response message?

**Versions**

```
Python==2.7.10
Django==1.11.4
djangorestframework==3.6.3
```

**Model**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), null=False, unique=True)
    first_name = models.TextField(_('first name'), null=False)
    last_name = models.TextField(_('last name'), null=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(_('admin'), default=False)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(_('create on'), auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(_('updated on'), auto_now=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff'), default=False)
    activation_key = models.CharField(_('email validation key'), default='', max_length=256)
```

**View**

```
class ActivateViewSet(generics.ListAPIView):

    queryset = User.objects
    serializer_class = ActivationSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        activation_key = self.kwargs['activation_key']
        if User.objects.all().filter(activation_key=activation_key).exists():
            User.objects.all().filter(activation_key=activation_key).update(is_active=True)
            return Response({'message': 'key accepted'}, status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
        raise NotFound('activation key not found')
```

**Serializer**

```
class ActivationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email',)
```

**Traceback**

```
File "/Users/*/.virtualenvs/video_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.response = get_response(request)
File "/Users/*/.virtualenvs/video_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/Users/*/.virtualenvs/video_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/*/.virtualenvs/video_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/*/.virtualenvs/video_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/*/.virtualenvs/video_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  489.response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "/Users/*/.virtualenvs/video_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
  449.self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
File "/Users/*/.virtualenvs/video_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  486.response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/*/.virtualenvs/video_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py" in get
  201.return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/*/.virtualenvs/video_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py" in list
  48.return Response(serializer.data)
File "/Users/*/.virtualenvs/video_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in data
  739.ret = super(ListSerializer, self).data
File "/Users/*/.virtualenvs/video_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in data
  263.self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
File "/Users/*/.virtualenvs/video_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in to_representation
  657.self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
File "/Users/*y/.virtualenvs/video_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in __iter__
  121.'The response content must be rendered before it can be iterated over.'

Exception Type: ContentNotRenderedError at /api/account/activate/849c40665175e56709855cc7aec2b16c05a4d977b3b083790334c6bc01f6e522/
Exception Value: The response content must be rendered before it can be iterated over.
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`get_queryset` expects a return type to be a `queryset` not a `Response` object. You need to change your code to something like

```
def get_queryset(self):
        activation_key = self.kwargs['activation_key']
        if User.objects.all().filter(activation_key=activation_key).exists():
            users = User.objects.all().filter(activation_key=activation_key)
                                      .update(is_active=True)
            return user
```

Now since you want to send a custom response it can't be done in `get_queryset`. You have to override your serializer's create method. Below is a general example for how to override this.

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        if not serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=False):
            return Response({"Fail": "blablal", status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response({"Success": "msb blablabla"}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

Comment: thank you for your feedback. I kinda figured trying to send a custom response with `get_queryset()` was the issue. I do have a question; since I'm using a `GET` would create still work? I'm very new to Django, but I've figured out that there is a lot of "magic" that happens with Django. When I use `create()` will that fire off with a `GET` method?

Comment: create goes for every kind of request since it is the method that creates your response for the request.

Comment: Ah, didn't know that :)

Comment: hello @Mike can you show me how you managed it to work ?
thanks in advance